# How much information can be stored in a system with synthetic dimensions?

Tags: information-theory

Okay this is a completely serious question and keep in mind I have a PhD in theoretical condensed matter physics, in which I have somewhat of a specialization in Floquet physics. So as the title says, 'How much information can be stored in a system with synthetic dimensions?' So the principle of the Bekenstein bound says that there is only so much entropy or information that you can store within a three dimensional space or four dimensional space, including time. So let's say that we already apply the Bekenstein bound to four dimensional space. But what if you include synthetic dimensions? If we apply the equivalent of the Bekenstein bound to a six dimensional space, will the information density end up working out to be the same as if you apply the Bekenstein bound to a four dimensional space or will you be able to store more information within this six dimensional space? Basically, this is a question of whether you can create a bigger on the inside space, like in Doctor Who.

I feel like this question is not an unscientific question because it is legitimately a question as opposed to imposing various beliefs on other people. Also, I feel as though a quantum computing forum is as good a place to ask this question as any other forum.

Here are a couple good sources for explaining sythetic dimensions:https://www.azoquantum.com/Article.aspx?ArticleID=303 , https://opg.optica.org/optica/fulltext.cfm?uri=optica-5-11-1396&id=400075

Comment: Could you please explain what are synthetic dimensions?

Comment: @MartinVesely I have attached a couple sources that explain synthetic dimensions. Basically, I understand it as utilizing extra degrees of freedom to do stuff like setting up sites that 'particles' can hop between in higher dimensional space. For example, I believe that you can set up these sites in frequency space.

Comment: I'd venture to guess Physics SE is a better platform for this question. Also, I'd guess the answer to your question is no (based on my understanding of Bekenstein bound) but I don't have enough familiarity with the notion of synthetic dimensions to post a proper answer.